# Mockito verify interaction with created mocks added to thread local listeners

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking

I'm using mockito to verify after each tests the number of interactions with my mocks. Some tests may have a lot of mocks so in order to avoid a long list of arguments when calling `Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions` I tried to add those mock to a list via `Mockito.framework().addListener`.

My test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyClass.class, MockitoConfig.class})
@SpringBootTest
public class MyClassTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Autowired
    private MockCollector mockCollector;

    @MockBean
    private MyMock myMock;

    @After
    public void after() {
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockCollector.getMocks().toArray());
    }

    @Test
    ...
}
```

My configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class MockitoConfig {

    @Bean
    public MockCollector mockCollector() {
        return new MockCollector();
    }

    public class MockCollector {

        private final List<Object> createdMocks = new ArrayList<>();

        public List<Object> getMocks() {
            return createdMocks;
        }

        public MockCollector() {
            Mockito.framework().addListener((MockCreationListener) (mock, settings) -> createdMocks.add(mock));
        }
    }
}
```

I created this configuration class so the whole addListener thing is only called once to avoid any `RedundantListenerException`.

The thing here is that my list of mocks is empty when queried in the `after` method. When I move the MockCollector's code directly in the `after` method it works great in the first test and obviously fails after the second because of a `RedundantListenerException`.

What am I missing here? Is there another way to perform what I want here?

Comment: My comment is more of a question, since I'm a JEE not a Spring guy. This being sad, is there a chance that for each test method a new @Autowired's constructor is being called, but in the second and later runs the mocks are already in place and the listener doesn't fire? Can you put a debug in `MockCollector`'s constructor? Can you make your @Autowired a singleton? (unless Spring already does that, disregard the comment then)

Comment: Spring does make it a singleton. And while in debug mode, after the first test the constructor is not called again.